# How to move buttons on dialog header?

Tags: css, sass

I'm want to move 3 buttons to the right (save, edit, delete buttons). Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?
Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0kc5AwkIFI7vBX7gvcr4?p=preview)

```
<p-dialog
[(visible)]="display" [draggable] = 'false'>
<p-header>
ACTIVE ALERT
  <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-save" (click)="saveAlert()">
  </button>
  <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-pencil" (click)="editItem()">
  </button>
  <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash"></button>
</p-header>
  <textarea [rows]="7" [cols]="60">
  </textarea>
</p-dialog>
```

I also tried doing:

> "float:right"

```
<div style = "float:right">
  <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-save" (click)="saveAlert()"></button>
 <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-pencil" (click)="editItem()"></button>
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash"></button>
</div>
```

But it moves all the buttons to the right and moves the **CLOSE (X)** button to the left

**NOTE:**

- Click on Show button to see my dialog that has the buttons on the header.
- I want to move all the buttons to the right and **keep** the close button all the way to the right. The **delete** button and close button should be next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this in your CSS file :

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

with :

```
<div style = "float:right">
  <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-save" (click)="saveAlert()"></button>
 <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-pencil" (click)="editItem()"></button>
<button pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash"></button>
</div>
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3QcMuXJt7ZfM66PAt9aA?p=preview)

Comment: I added a Plunker

Comment: Is that okay now ?